# Delete the Twitter Account Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios5, twitter, settings, social-media

In my application I am using Twiiter to Tweet.
If In user's iphone twitter account is not set then on the screen one alert pop up to set twitter account and on clicking on setting button it will direct user to setting's screen.

I would like to delete stored twitter account.

from going to setting screen by my application or programmatically.

My code is this

```
if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
   {

       NSLog(@"delete the account");


   }
   else{
        TWTweetComposeViewController *viewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
        viewController.view.hidden = YES;

        viewController.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
            NSLog(@"coming twitt 11111");
            if (result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {

                NSLog(@"coming twitt");
                [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
            }
        };
        [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO];

        [viewController.view endEditing:YES];

   }
```

any Help Like link, tutorial, sample code or direction will appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to the delete the account programmatically, this would be a huge issue if you could.

Also start with iOS 5.1 you are no longer able to open the setting.app.

The only thing you can do is explain to your user how to delete there account.

Comment: Given this, are there any suggestions on how to automate unit testing of twitter related authentication ui / functions? i.e. My app has different behaviour depending on if there exists a system Twitter account and I want to unit test both cases.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method in `ACAccountStore` for remove accounts

```
removeAccount:<#(ACAccount *)#> withCompletionHandler:<#^(BOOL success, NSError *error)completionHandler#>
```

but it gives this error message `The application is not permitted to delete Twitter accounts`

Comment: I've never managed to get this method to work, I guess it is for account that your has registered with the `ACAccountStore`.